# Por que não temos perguntas como "o que é a linguagem X"

Tags: suporte

Não fiz uma busca completa com todas as linguagens, mas, em geral não encontrei perguntas como ["O que é C#"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308621/o-que-%C3%A9-o-c-como-funciona-como-e-quando-usar/), acho esse tipo de pergunta interessante, e o resumo da tag da linguagem não é completo o suficiente. O mais próximo que encontrei é perguntas como [O que é o NPM e o Node?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157034/o-que-%C3%A9-o-npm-e-o-node), porém a linguagem de progamação é o JavaScript e o Node é apenas a plataforma.

Aproveitando, gostaria de saber como posso melhorar a minha pergunta que foi marcada como ampla demais, dividir em perguntas menores?

Comment: Exemplo: [O que é a linguagem de programação Rust?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249783/5878)

Comment: Exemplo: [O que é Prisma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220220/5878)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é um pouco isso. Fazer uma pergunta assim está no escopo, mas se não for bem feita pode ser considerada ampla.

Quando se pergunta algo de linguagem obscura, que poucos ouviram falar, e quer saber superficialmente, ok. Se quer saber algo de linguagem bem conhecida e o que tem na wiki da tag, aí começa complicar e é debatível se pode ou não perguntar, afinal não tem dup do que já "tá no Google" ou da wiki de tag. A pergunta tende ser ampla demais,

Mas pode ser feita de forma específica, pode não querer saber tudo, pode querer algum ponto que não está na wiki.

Eu costumo dizer que qualquer pergunta pode ser feita, exceto as obviamente muito fora de escopo, e as claramente duplicatas.

Pergunta clara, específica, que não exige um capítulo de um livro para responder e que não esteja pedindo opinião sempre pode ser feita, mas precisa de cuidado, tem que se dedicar a fazer algo que dê pra responder de forma adequada. Inclusive que no fundo temos as perguntas que deveriam ser mescadas (dup, mas precisa mudar outras coisas), as removidas (off, sem salvação) e as fechadas, pra depois serem removidas se não resolver o problema, sendo que os fechamentos deveria ter algo mais granular, não só: não claro, amplo ou opinião.

A pergunta ali é claramente ampla e a tentativa de resposta já apagada é sofrível. Ainda bem que foi de um usuário experiente e teve o bom senso de apagar. Tenho mais críticas quem votou a favor (curiosamente um usuário que criticou uma resposta minha que ia mais ou menos na mesma linha, mas acho que era bem mais pertinente que esta, talvez ele tenha lembrado disso :P )

Dá pra responder a pergunta, mas é muita coisa, de forma geral algumas partes podem ser feitas individualmente. O motivo existente é ruim porque ele não deixa claro se o fechamento é porque:

- tem várias em perguntas em uma
- pede um capítulo de um livro
- não tem detalhes suficientes para centrar em uma coisa
- não consegue indicar o que quer e que só não é "não clara" porque o problema é que muita coisa pode ser respondida e pode ou não estar certa, ninguém sabe
- é uma *poll*/*survey*/*shopping*/*list question*
- ou tem algum outro problema de amplitude

Algumas acho que já está na wiki. tem frase que já daria algumas perguntas diferentes. Algumas são duplicatas. Algumas não tem salvação nem sozinhas de tão ampla, chegar ser um livro, nem um capítulo só. Notou como é até difícil fechar por um motivo, porque eles são variados, a ampla encaixou bem.

Em todas as versões é muito ampla e provavelmente a melhorzinha é a que é mais simples, mas ainda assim, não diz o que quer saber de fato, pode ser muita coisa.

Então ela em si não tem salvação. ver as que não foram respondidas, e fazê-las de forma mais individual, de forma que não pareça que quer só uma wiki de tag mais completa, com clareza, que seja coesa, o que pode ser mais de uma pergunta junta se for pertinente ao mesmo assunto (e isso nem sempre é fácil de entender, porque alguém pode argumentar ali que é tudo sobre C#), aí mesmo que alguma saia meio torta dá pra salvar. Faça com cuidado.

A pergunta aqui é pertinente, acho que precismos de mecanismos para expressar melhor algumas necessidades da comunidade, e que até quero falar sobre, mas nunca fui instigado adequadamente a fazê-lo, e se esperar eu ter tempo para fazer por conta, melhor sentar em local bem confortável. Mas essencialmente é algo como um Wiki mais oficial, menos acanhado como o que tem hoje. A SE reconhece que ele é ruim, mas nunca fez nada pra melhorar, tornar cidadão de primeira classe. O finado Docs era um caminho, que tinha problemas, mas desistiram.
[image: Desistir jamais, o sucesso só vem de quem tenta outra vez]

Tem sido raro boas perguntas no meta que produzem conhecimento e esclarecimento :)

Comment: Na minha pergunta original, o que mais me interessa saber no momento é quando usar o C#, acredita que essa pergunta pode ser considerada muito ampla ou não clara (desde que bem feita)?

Comment: Outra pergunta que tenho curiosidade e a relação entre o CLR e a JVM, acha que vale apena criar outras duas perguntas ou uma e editar a anteriror com apenas esses dois assuntos separados?

Comment: "O que é o C#, como funciona, como e quando usar?" Isto é bem amplo. Só a primeira é meio tola, a segunda é extramente ampla por mais de um motivo, idem pra terceira, e a quarta salvaria se colocasse um contexto, se fosse muito clara, com muito cuidado. Se fizer bem pode perguntar sobre os *runtimes*, que é diferente da linguagem, mas note que já tem perguntas sobre isto, se certifique que não está perguntando a mesma coisa já perguntada.

Comment: Fiz a [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309322/), porém, como não conheço muito bem a linguagem, não sei bem como perguntar, se puder, por favor a melhore